# Is 「＿＿といいます」 acceptable when introducing myself? Or is it considered improper?

Tags: grammar

**Another question:**
What is the best way to introduce myself in a neutral setting that is neither proper nor improper and still natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its fine. But the most natural and, to answer your question, neutral way to introduce yourself is just [your name]です. If you are trying to be formal you should probably just say と申します. This is fairly common even outside of business interactions.